# ServiceNow - How to copy the URLs of projects in a remote/shared server folder?

Tags: url, hyperlink, field, project, servicenow

My requisite is the following one: How can I have in ServiceNow, in a custom field in table pm_project the url address (link) to an internal server (like \my_server\shared\filed).

URL type of field supports only https address.

I tried with the syntax ///\ in personalize dictionary (calculated value) (I read it in another similar thread), but it is not working...

Any suggestion?

Skender

Answer (score 1):

Storing an internal server or local file uri isn't the problem, it's linking to it from the web page that displays it. 
The browser is preventing you from linking to local files from an https:// page because it poses a substantial security risk.

To actually support linking to local/remote files within your browser, you likely have to install a browser extension like [LocalLinks for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/locallinks/jllpkdkcdjndhggodimiphkghogcpida) which allows linking via the `file://` protocol prefix.

Also, a mozillaZine article briefly explaining this limitation and ways around it in IE and FireFox: [Links to local pages do not work](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Issues_:_Links_to_Local_Pages_Don%27t_Work)